# VUEJS/X Data Template loads before my computed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, computed-properties

first of all I'm sorry for my bad English, I'm using a translator.

I'm a beginner with VUE and VUE X, there are surely big mistakes.

I have a problem with VUE, currently I am trying to display a publication thanks to its ID.

Here is my DATA :

```
    data(){
    return {
        list: [this.$store.dispatch('allPublications')],
        id:'',
        feed: '',
    }
},
```

Here is my STORE action:

```
    publicationId:({commit}, messages) => {
  instance.get('/publications/' + messages.id)
  .then(function(response){
    commit('setMessage', response.data.publication)
    console.log(response)
    this.feed = response.data.publication.data
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
  })
},
```

Here is my computed:

```
    computed: {
    ...mapState({
        user: 'profileUser',
        publication: 'publicationFeed',
        message: 'publicationInfos'
        }),

        message(){
            return this.$store.state.message;
        },
},
```

Here is my state :

```
    setMessage: function(state, message){
  state.message = message
},
```

Here is my template :

```
<template>
           <div class="card-body" @click="publicationId(message.id)">
            <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ message.User.username }}</span>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between align-items-md-center">
                <p class="card-text d-flex flex-start">{{ message.message }}</p>
            </div>
            <span class="message__date">{{ message.createdAt.split('T')[0]}}</span>
        </div>
        <img class="card-img-top" alt="..." :src="message.image">
```

Some screenshot to help you more :

[VUE google chrome tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r5pA.png)

[Before reloading the page, everything is OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55UmY.png)

[After reloading the page, everything is going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSYtc.png)

Everything works fine as long as I don't reload the page, as soon as I reload it I get an error, my computed value disappears and I can't get the data from my computed.

I have searched a lot of information without being able to solve this problem, thanks to you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that i've solved this issue doing this :

```
    data() {
    return {
        componentLoaded: false,
        list: [this.$store.dispatch('allPublications')],
        id: '',
        feed: '',
    }
},
```

In the mounted :

```
    mounted() {
    this.componentLoaded = true;
    this.id = this.$route.params.id;
    this.$store.dispatch('publicationId', { id: this.$route.params.id })
},
```

In the computed :

```
    computed: {
    message() {
        if (!this.componentLoaded) {
            return null
        } else {
            return this.$store.state.message;
        }
    },
},
```

And I add a v-if in the template

```
<template>
<div class="verification" v-if="componentLoaded === true">
    <div class="card-body" @click="publicationId(message.id)">
        <span class="badge bg-secondary">{{ message.User.username }}</span>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <div class="card-text d-flex justify-content-between align-items-md-center">
            <p class="card-text d-flex flex-start">{{ message.message }}</p>
        </div>
        <span class="message__date">{{ message.createdAt.split('T')[0] }}</span>
    </div>
    <img class="card-img-top" alt="..." :src="message.image" />
</div>
<div v-else>
    <h1>test</h1>
</div>
```

It worked for me, I hope it will help for those who needs.